# .find within .map() returns undefined - JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

```
return valuesArray.map((objValue) => {
         Dataset.find(dataObj => dataObj.value === objValue)
});
```

it returns undefined. However, if I use forEach and push values into an new array, it works.

Comment: you aren't returning anything. either use `return` or drop the curlies

Comment: @CodeBreaker This behavior is strange.Even I ma doing same and I am getting undefined, even I have returned properly. @Daniel A. White can you help here ?
```resources.map((resource) => members.find((member) => member.identifier === resource))```

Comment: @Vipulw please post a new question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 7):

You can also check with `filter` to check for `undefined`.

```
return valuesArray.map((objValue) => {
        return Dataset.find(dataObj => dataObj.value === objValue)
}).filter(y => y != undefined);
```

So it will not return the `undefined` from the `valuesArray` also.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return value.

With anonymous functions, if you encase the function in curly braces, you have to explicitly return a value.

- `() => 1`: returns 1
- `() => { 1 }`: returns undefined
- `() => ({})`: returns {}

To answer your question, here are 2 methods that will work:

```
return valuesArray.map((objValue) => {
         return Dataset.find(dataObj => dataObj.value === objValue)
});
```

or

```
return valuesArray.map((objValue) => Dataset.find(dataObj => dataObj.value === objValue));
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to why the OP's code didn't work and what you've changed